# Place bootstrap select button inside input box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the select option inside the input box (left-side)

```
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col one">
                    <label class="label">Loan amount</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      
                      <select class="form-select btn-primary input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected>USD</option>
                        <option value="1">ETH</option>
                        <option value="2">USDC</option>
                      </select>
                      
                      <input class="form-control loan" type="text" style="direction: rtl;" placeholder="0.00" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    </div>

                    <label class="label" for="customRange1">Duration</label>
                      <div class="range">
                        <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And also precise your bootstrap version, please

Answer (score 2):

here is demo code on how to put selection inside input with bootstrap v3.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
      <div style="padding: 100px 100px 10px;">
         <form class="bs-example bs-example-form" role="form">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <select class="form-select btn-primary input-group-text btn btn-default 
                       dropdown-toggle" id="basic-addon1" aria-label="Default select example" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding: 8px;">
                        <option selected>USD</option>
                        <option value="1">ETH</option>
                        <option value="2">USDC</option>
                      </select> 
                     </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div><!-- /input-group -->
               </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --><br>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```